# Can I move my Paraview question from SO to here?

Tags: discussion

I have the impression that here there are more Paraview users than on StackOverflow. I already posted a few questions there, should I migrate them? Or cross post?

Comment: I personally think that Paraview-related questions are suitable for CS, because it's a scientific application designed for scientific postprocessing needs. I presume any computational scientist has been exposed to paraview (or vtk-based visualisation applications) at some point of their careers/education/etc, so we could benefit their experience here. This is why I have created the `paraview` tag. So, if you have future postprocessing questions (mayavi,visit,...) in relevance to scientific computing, they should be asked on CS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never a good idea to cross-post questions on the stack exchange.  We highly discourage it.  If you haven't received a suitable answer on stack overflow, you might be able to get an answer here.  No guarantees, but it's worth a shot.  My recommendation is to delete your old post on SO, and repost it here.